# How to use Semantic Versioning on Existing Multi Component Codebase?

Tags: open-source, version-control, versioning, semantic-versioning

I am working on a multi contributor project, having ~2500 Commits. It has multiple components, i.e. Frontend, Backend and Data Processor/DB Ingestion.

Now that we are expecting more contributors, a Versioning System should be implemented, and should be displayed on footer of Frontend, as `vA.B.C`, where A = Big Change, B = New Features and C = Patch Fix. But, the issue is that we are having a very complex multi component software and has many commits.

How should I approach this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, what's your issue. Do you want to know what version value you should use?

Comment: First thing first, you need to identify **why** you want to version your components. What problems are you trying to solve? What are the pain points of the existing system?

Answer (score 2):

The semantic versioning is meant to manage the dependencies between components, based on their [public API](https://semver.org/#spec-item-1):

> Software using Semantic Versioning MUST declare a public API. This API
>   could be declared in the code itself or exist strictly in
>   documentation. However it is done, it should be precise and
>   comprehensive.

The whole [versioning logic](https://semver.org) is building on this public API and the backward (in)compatiblity it offers.

So, in principle:

- If you have a single codebase that provides several internal components, you should have a single version number. Changes in private code (and private component API) may lead to [minor versions](https://semver.org/#spec-item-7).
- If however your codebase provides several components that offer each a public API and that could be deployed independently, it may be a better option to have a different version number for each component. The overall product should then also have its own version, that evolves independently of the component's version.

*Note: In the second case, if the components could be deployed independently, why not put them in a distinct repo ? In all cases,  if a version is to be displayed in the front-end, display the version of the main product, and offer a possibility to display the also the list of components with their own versions.*